# XTS data taking up too much space in memory?

Tags: r, xts, zoo, quantmod

I am using GetSymbols from quantmod in the following way:

```
temp0 <- getSymbols("AAPL",src = 'yahoo',from=Sys.Date()-100000,to = Sys.Date(),auto.assign=FALSE);
```

And I get large xts object using up little space.

```
temp0   Large xts (59664 elements, 546.2 Kb)
```

However, sometimes the xts objects take way too much space. Here are some of my objects.

```
temp1   Large xts (34848 elemnts, 25.5 Mb)
t12     Large xts (36 elements, 25.2 Mb)
```

With t12 being the result of head(temp1) and here is t12:

```
structure(t12)
                    Bid.Price Bid.Size Ask.Price Ask.Size Trade.Price Volume
2019-05-29 17:00:01  116.4922       51  116.5000      143    116.4922    208
2019-05-29 17:00:02  116.4922       71  116.5000      142    116.5000      2
2019-05-29 17:00:04  116.4844      427  116.4922       92    116.4844     72
2019-05-29 17:00:08  116.4922       83  116.5000      156    116.4922     21
2019-05-29 17:01:01  116.4922       71  116.5000      128    116.4922     34
2019-05-29 17:01:08  116.5000       13  116.5078      228    116.4922    192
```

I did find that if I use attributes(t12) I find that **#na.action** as well as **attr(,"index")** contain many values, over 2 million.

temp1 were very large data sets from which I filtered most data, but it seems that the object kept old useless data in **#na.action** and **attr(,"index")** if not more.

I don't know why this happens, but how can I clean it up? How can get my 6 row t12 to be the proper minimal size?

If it helps here is the full attributes output with max.print=10:

```
> attributes(t12)
$class
[1] "xts" "zoo"

$.indexCLASS
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tclass
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$na.action
 [1]  1  3  6  7  8 12 13 15 16 17
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2201657 entries ]
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
attr(,"index")
 [1] 1519772400 1519772402 1519772407 1519772409 1519772410 1519772420 1519772424 1519772428 1519772429 1519772430
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2201657 entries ]

$index
[1] 1559167201 1559167202 1559167204 1559167208 1559167261 1559167268
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "America/Chicago"
attr(,"tclass")
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$dim
[1] 6 6

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
NULL

$dimnames[[2]]
[1] "Bid.Price"   "Bid.Size"    "Ask.Price"   "Ask.Size"    "Trade.Price" "Volume"
```

How can I remove the excess information from the xts?

**UPDATE**

I seem to have found a workaround to the issue based on my code above.

```
t12 <- rbind(t12[1,],t12)
t12[1,1] < NA
t12 <- na.omit(t12)
```

I add the top row of the data to the top and set the first entry to NA.
Then when I do na.omit on the data set the resting data is the same as t12 originally, but clean without the extra bad data.

The issue is that I already use na.omit() to create the temp1 set and don't know why sometimes na.omit() does not clean the data correctly? possibly with very large data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `na.omit()` function adds the `na.action` attribute. This attribute contains the locations and index values for all the observations that were removed. It is added to be consistent with other methods for `na.omit()`.

Your work-around makes the object smaller because it overwrites the `na.action` attribute with values that represent the one missing value you added to the beginning of the series.

Setting the `na.action` attribute to `NULL` is a clearer work-around.

```
R> x <- .xts(1:1000, 1:1000); set.seed(21); is.na(x) <- sample(1000, 100)
R> y <- na.omit(x)
R> object.size(x)
9176 bytes
R> object.size(y)
9720 bytes
R> attr(y, "na.action") <- NULL
R> object.size(y)
8376 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a na.omit() alternative that skips the na.action entirely?

Comment: There isn't currently an alternative. I'm going to propose something like `na.drop()` to the zoo+xts team.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found a workaround to the issue based on my code above.

```
t12 <- rbind(t12[1,],t12)
t12[1,1] <- NA
t12 <- na.omit(t12)
```

I add the top row of the data to the top and set the first entry to NA.
Then when I do na.omit on the data set the resting data is the same as t12 originally, but clean without the extra bad data.